# Simple melody recognition based on a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, sound

Is there a way to implement a simple melody recognition using a hobby-level microcontroller board like Arduino or Tiva Launchpad? By "melody" I mean a sequence of 4-5 clear notes, produced by a musical instrument. The device should recognize the stored pattern.

I am starting on this project now and I was wondering if there are any implementations o draw ideas from.

Comment: Of course there is a way. Sample the sound, do a running FFT (or DFT, or whatever), identify the dominant frequencies over time, and match that against the stored patterns. This is quite an amount of work :)

Comment: FM synthesis or Karplus-Strong, start reading.

Comment: Thanks. I have found some code to implement FFT on Arduino here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,38153.0.html 
I will try that out.

Comment: Might be worth googling DTMF detectors/decoders, and also the venerable XR2211 FSK decoder IC.

Comment: The shazam method won't work for identifying a melody played, say, on a different instrument.

Comment: Here is some pitch tracking code with explination of how it works you could use as a first step. It goes so far as to identify the note being played at a given time, so a lot of the work is done. http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Answer (score 1):

If the individual notes can be sine waves or square waves then you should be able to pin-point each part of the signal as a musical note. I say this because if the signal is a rich blend of many instruments then deciding what is the melody becomes a nightmare.

You then need to look up what the frequencies are and recognize that in music, one semitone (even-tempered) is approximately 1.0595 higher in frequency than the note below i.e. if one note is 440 Hz then the note immediately above is 466.2Hz.

This can help you provide a noise-gap so you can recognize when a note actually changes.

This all goes wrong when someone is playing violin because of the notes gliding between notes. Ditto on a fret-less bass or trombone.

Good luck - it sounds difficult.

Comment: Thanks! My case is simpler than what you are saying, so I will probably go for a "guitar tuner" solution